# Android Wifi Receiver broadcast late response

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I've done this wifi receiver where I want do an action when the wifi is enabled...

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        WifiManager wManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        if (isWifiEnabled(wManager)) {
           new MyTask().execute();
        }
    }

    public static boolean isWifiEnabled(WifiManager wifi) {
        if (wifi==null) return false;
        if (wifi.getWifiState()!= wifi.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

...and this is my manifest for the receiver...

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".receiver.WifiReceiver" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

...but the receiver do the task too late (about 10-60 seconds or much) from the wifi switching.

Where is my error? There is another method to do this without use a Service?

Comment: Can you try STATE_CHANGE instead of WIFI_STATE_CHANGED? I'm not 100% sure of it reducing the time, but in my apps I use it so maybe give it a try

Comment: Also, can you post logs where exactly it takes time to execute the task?

Comment: it receive the system intent late i think. Now i try STATE_CHANGE

Answer (score 1):

while registering the receiver use the intent filter as WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION

```
 BroadcastReceiver wifiStateChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
          //your code    
        }
    }
};
```

you need to register your broadcast receiver in Oncreate or Onstart methods like this

```
 wifiStateChangeFilter.addAction(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(wifiStateChangeReceiver, wifiStateChangeFilter);
```

but make sure you are unregistering the receivers after work is done.If you are registering in oncreate() method you need to unRegister() in onDestroy() method.If you are Registering in OnStart() means you need to unregister in OnStop() method.